# Pig Latin Translator code not working

Tags: java, string, translators

I've been making a pig Latin translator, which basically crops out single words from the user's sentence, pass it down to the translator method which will look for a, e, i, o, u, letter-by-letter to translate the word. Theoretically I  think it would work just fine, but my code has something going wrong. I think it's the charAt() thing, but it's look pretty messy considering I use all sorts of substrings, length and index related stuff. Can someone help me fix my code? I would also like to know if there is a better way to write this. Thanks in adv.

```
import java.util.*;
import static java.lang.System.*;

public class PigLatinTranslator {
    public static Scanner scan = new Scanner(in);

public static void main(String args[]){
    String translated = "";
    out.println("Enter the sentence you want to translate");
    String input = scan.nextLine ();
    input = input.toUpperCase ();
    while(input.length() > 0){
        int a = input.indexOf (" ");
        if (a == -1){
            a = 1;
        }
        String stripped = input.substring (0, a);
        input = input.substring (a+1, input.length());
        translated += translator(stripped);
    }
    out.println(translated);
}

public static String translator(String input) {
    int index = 0;
    String implement, sum = "";
    if(input.charAt (index) == 65 || input.charAt (index) == 69 || input.charAt (index) == 73 ||
       input.charAt (index) == 79 || input.charAt (index) == 85){
        input += "-ay ";
        out.println(input);
        return input;
    }
    while(input.charAt (index) != 65 && input.charAt (index) != 69 && input.charAt (index) != 73 &&
            input.charAt(index) != 79 && input.charAt(index) != 85){
        implement = Character.toString(input.charAt (index));
        sum += implement;
        index ++;
    }
    input = input.substring(index, input.length()) + "-" + sum + "ay";
    return input;
}
```

}

Comment: What issues are you running into?

Comment: The compiler is saying something about string index out of bound. I'm pretty sure it happens down in the translator method, and caused by a charAt command, according to the compiler

Comment: I imagine that you would get a OOB Exception in the bottom `while` as you are not checking the `index` is greater than the length of `input`. Also the substring

Comment: @Ubuntu4EVA can you update your post with the stack trace? It should include a line number where you’re going out of bounds.

Comment: i currently don't have my computer, so can you guys compile it and see personally what the problem ia?

Comment: er - read my comment

Comment: sorry, I forgot to explain. I'm learning things and your comment is kinda hard to understand for me.

Answer (score 0):

This is one of those times where you should have just used regex

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Enter the sentence you want to translate");
    String input = scan.nextLine();
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

    for (String word : input.toUpperCase().split("\\s+")) {
        builder.append(translate(word)).append(' ');
    }

    String translated = builder.toString().trim();
    System.out.println(translated);
}

public static String translate(String word) {
    return word.replaceAll("(?i)\\b([^aeiou]+)(\\w+)", "$2-$1ay");
}
```

In plain English: split the sentence into words, take each word and move the starting consonants to the end with an 'ay' attached, then rejoin the words.

P.S.: Since you're new to this, I should explain more. Basically in Java, there are special tools meant specifically for manipulating text. Two of these are regular expressions and `StringBuilder`. The easiest way to build something like a Pig Latin translator is to split the string into words:`String.split()` splits the string, `\\s+` means split where there are spaces. Then you transform the words using regex, and join them back together using a StringBuilder, which is like a String you can modify.

The regex I used is `(?i)\\b([^aeiou]+)(\\w+)", "$2-$1ay` which means: starting from the beginning of the word (`\\b`), find the letters that are not (`^`) vowels (`[aeiou]+`), then find all the letters after them (`\\w+`). When you find these two groups ($1 and $2), move $1 to the end (`$2-$1`) and add an `ay` after it (`$2-$1ay`).

Comment: Every time i forget to mention that i'm a noob(which can be seen pretty obviously in my code), someone just posts a code that I'm unable to understand half of. Still, thanks for helping me.

Comment: @Ubuntu4EVA I've explained a bit more.

Comment: that made it a lot clearer, thanks! though I would prefer an easieer

Comment: any chance my code can be modified so that it works with any sentence?